# Django: defining a model to make a template

Tags: django, models

I am new to creating models in Django and I want to make a model, which allows you to fill in the title, some texts for on the template and the path to this template. I am trying to get the answer off of the Django Example Project, but I just don't understand the models, is there anybody who can help me on how to write such a model?

My code in the models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
    project_title = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    project_information = models.Charfield(max_length=400)
```

where project_name is the link to the template

I don't know if this is a correct begin or that it should be something completely different.

Comment: So what is wrong with this code?

Comment: I don't know how to create a template in this model and assign a link to it, in other words, can you write from the models.py to the urls.py and views.py, to create a link for a template

Comment: You can start by reading the django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're asking ways to use the information in a model (object data) in a template.

If so, template isn't created in a model, you can send your object(s) to a template  by rendering a template in the corresponding view of the model. You'll append the necessary information (queryset and other optional dict elements) in the view and send it to the template.

How you can use the information in the template depends on your view method. For function based views like this:

```
  def home_view(request):
        contests = Contests.objects.filter(id<5)
        context={'contests':contests}
        return render(request, 'home/home.html', context)
```

You can access the data in a queryset in the template, like this:

```
{% for contest in contests %}
   //do something with the single contest data
{% endfor %}
```

You can directly access the non-plural values like this:

```
{% if not random_contest == None %}
   //do something with the random contest data
{% endif %}
```

Additionally, there are class based views but it looks like you are at a very early stage of learning Django, so you won't need it for now.

[See the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/) about views.
[See the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/) about shortcut functions.